# How can I mock to an @autowired @Qualifier attribute in a Service?

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I have a service with an attribute like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("test")
private String test;
```

This attribute come from context xml file.

I become nothing in unit test, probably that a correct behavior in unit test. But can I mock this attribute to become a value?

for example:

```
when(test).thenReturn("a string");
```

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19682293/3890673) help?

Comment: I not see if that can be helping. Even if I make my String test public...

Comment: Why are y ou autowiring a String? That should come from a property file.Generally  defining simple things like strings/integers as beans isn't a wise thing to do.

Comment: There are a couple of answer under that link (plus some explanation why private autowired fields may cause trouble); I tried to answer the most common ones below. @m-deinum: A String is a perfectly reasonable type of bean, even if it comes from a property file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment making the field public is an option. You can just set it afterwards:

```
myMock = Mock(MyClass)
myMock.test = "foobar"
```

Besides that you could add a setter, leaving the field private. Or you could try `@InjectMocks` or Spring's `ReflectionTestUtils`, both from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19682293/3890673).

Comment: I don't understand because I have already tested, but that works fine with ReflectionTestUtils. Thanks you